# How to force a division in tree and locate covariates that explain the variable in TraMineR?

Tags: r, traminer

my goal here is simple:

I have a bunch of sequences, and a few sequences of interest (that do contain a certain subsequence). I want to force that division and use a tree method (either CART or CHAID) to explore covariates able to explain my binary variable (containing or not the subsequence).

The sequences I'm talking about are event sequences.

Any help would be appreciated ! thanks.

Comment: This question does not concern `TraMineR`. You should try the `rpart` tag. The `seqtree` and `disstree` functions of `TraMineR` have a `first=` argument. I don't think there is one in `rpart`. You may also look at `party`.